# Bootstrap 4 hide not close alerts

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, alert, bootstrap-4

As the title states, I'd like to know the best way to hide an alert so that we can have another alert without reloading the page.  There are several answers on here for BS3, but I'm hoping there's a better solution for BS4.
Here's my HTML:

```
<div style="display: none;" class="alert alert-danger alert-with-icon" data-notify="container">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="alert-wrapper">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                      <i class="nc-icon nc-simple-remove"></i>
                  </button>
                  <div class="message"><i class="nc-icon nc-bell-55"></i>
                      My alert message.
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

And I'm using this to trigger the alert to being opened:

```
$('.alert').show();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "have another alert without reloading the page"? Do you want to write a function to hide and show alerts?

Answer (score 6):

You simply have to add an **on listener** to overwrite the default behaviour. This worked for me:

```
$(".alert").on("close.bs.alert", function () {
      $alertMsg.hide();
      return false;
});
```

This solution was provided by Winifred Cadap on his blog. You can find it [here](http://codexsquare.blogspot.de/2014/07/preventing-bootstrap-alert-from-being.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".alert").alert('close');
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide just use `$('.alert').hide();`

Check the below example

```js
$('.alert').show();
setTimeout(function(){ $('.alert').hide(); }, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="display: none;" class="alert alert-danger alert-with-icon" data-notify="container">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="alert-wrapper">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                      <i class="nc-icon nc-simple-remove"></i>
                  </button>
                  <div class="message"><i class="nc-icon nc-bell-55"></i>
                      My alert message.
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to dismiss an alert inline. for that add `.alert-dismissible` class to your alert box

```
<div style="display: none;" class="alert alert-danger alert-with-icon alert-dismissible fade show" data-notify="container" role="alert">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="alert-wrapper">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                  <i class="nc-icon nc-simple-remove"></i>
              </button>
              <div class="message"><i class="nc-icon nc-bell-55"></i>
                  My alert message.
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

i modified your code. now `data-dismiss="alert"` attribute in your button trigger the javaScript functionality. i also added `fade show` class which gives a smooth animation.

i don't understand what you mean by

> hide an alert so that we can have another alert without reloading the page?

Comment: This will be implemented on a credit card form, so this alert should pop up when there is an error in a field on focus.  If you 'close' the alert and there's another error on a different field, using close will remove the alert completely from the DOM, and no future alerts from form will show.

Comment: one option you can add a click event to button which changes the display property.